# How to perform addition while displaying a node inside a foreach loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

My code is :

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,11}
        \draw (\x,0) +(-0.5,-.5)rectangle +(0.5,0.5);
    \foreach \x/\val in {0/9,1/5,2/13,3/19,4/12,5/8,6/7,7/4,8/21,9/2,10/6,11/11}
        \draw (\x,0) node {\val} (\x,-0.85) node{{\footnotesize \x+1}};
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0)++(-0.5,-.5) rectangle +(12,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

The output is :

[image: Output]

I want the text at the nodes to be the value of (x+1), but all I get is the text. How do I get the values of 1 through 12 below the array to point out the indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `evaluate` inside the `\foreach` loop:

```
\foreach \x/\val [evaluate=\x as \xx using \x+1] in {0/9,1/5,2/13,3/19,4/12,5/8,6/7,7/4,8/21,9/2,10/6,11/11} {
    \draw (\x,0) node {\val} (\x,-0.85) node{{\footnotesize \xx}};
}
```

This said, I would do this differently. First, you can have several commands inside a `\foreach` loop just by enclosing them in `{...}`, so you can get rid of one of the loops. Secondly, if you draw the nodes as rectangles this will take care of the line between adjacent boxes. Finally, since `\x` just counts the box you can "compute" this using `\count`, making the code easier to read and easier to write.

Putting this together gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={rectangle, draw, 
                                    minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm}]
        \foreach \val [count=\x, remember=\x] in {9,5,13,19,12,8,7,4,21,2,6,11} {
            \node[mybox,label=below:{\footnotesize\x}] at (\x,0) {\val};
        }
        \draw[ultra thick] (0.5,-0.5) rectangle +(\x,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

Notice that I have shifted your "big" box so that it starts from `(0.5,-0.5)` so as to avoid having to add `1` to `\x`. Also, the `mybox` style takes care of the line between the boxes. The `remmber` in the `\foreach` loop is so that the last value of `\x` can be used after the loop for drawing the frame.

The `rectangle,draw` in the style command draws a rectangle around the border of node. If you leave out the `minimum height` and `minimum width` then size of the rectangle will be only big enough to contain the contents of the node, which means that the "boxes" for the nodes will have different sizes. Specifying the `minimum height` and `minimum width` ensures that we get square boxes. Indeed, if we leave out the minimum height and width then we get:

[image]

If you wanted to put this into a macro then you could use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\boxes[1]{%
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm}]
    \foreach \val [count=\x, remember=\x] in {#1} {
        \node[mybox,label=below:{\footnotesize\x}] at (\x,0) {\val};
    }
    \draw[ultra thick] (0.5,-0.5) rectangle +(\x,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}

\boxes{9,5,13,19,12,8,7,4,21,2,6,11}

\boxes{9,5,13,19,1}

\end{document}
```

to give

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of using minimum width and minimum height? Sorry, if the explanation is obvious, I'm new to latex.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain what these do. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically set the length of the "big box" as described here:

`\draw[ultra thick] (1,0)++(-0.5,-.5) rectangle +(12,1);`

to be set to the size of the internal box? i.e., If I put 5 elements into the array, the outer box should also adjust to the size of the array of 5 elements, instead of 12.

Comment: `node[mybox, label=below:{\footnotesize\x}] at (\x,0) {\val};` saves you from using/typing two nodes.

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks. I should know this:) Will incorporate

Comment: @SomenathSinha Yes. I thought about adding this earlier but forgot. You just need to add `remember` to the `\foreach`. Will edit and also incorporate Ignasi's improvement.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution with a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10mm}]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 1/.style={nodes={mybox, anchor=center}},
    row 2/.style={font=\footnotesize, inner ysep=2mm}]
    {
        9 & 5 & 13 & 19 & 12 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 21 &  2 &  6 & 11\\
        1 & 2 &  3 &  4 &  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 &  9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
        };
    \draw[ultra thick] (A-1-1.north west) rectangle (A-1-12.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Column labels can be automatically defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10mm}]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 1/.style={nodes={mybox, anchor=center}},
    row 2/.style={font=\footnotesize, inner ysep=2mm, 
           nodes={node contents=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}},
    nodes in empty cells]
    {
        9 & 5 & 13 & 19 & 12 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 21 &  2 &  6 & 11\\
         &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
        };
    \draw[ultra thick] (A-1-1.north west) rectangle (A-1-12.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```