# Failed Nested Macro

Tags: macros

I'm trying to create number tracks for my students. They should look something like this.

[image]

I'd like to create a macro that makes an arbitrary number of them of an arbitrary length (x-max).

Note: The command `\numbertrack{20}` compiles to make the above image. The macro I made to make a whole bunch of those, `\mytracks`, does not compile.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\def\myscale{1.15}

\newcommand{\numbertrack}[1]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
\draw (0,0)--(#1,0);
\draw (0,1)--(#1,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,#1}
\draw (\x,0)--(\x,1);
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,#1}
\node[anchor=center] at (\x-0.5,0.5) {\huge\x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\vspace{1cm}
}

\newcommand{\mytracks}
{
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,...,20}
\numbertrack{\y}
}

\begin{document}

\mytracks

\end{document}
```

Comment: with `\foreach\y in {1,2,3,...,20}{ \numbertrack{\y} } `, the example compiles for me

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks. I didn't know I need the curly braces if there was only one command after a `\foreach`... I don't remember using them in TikZ unless there were at least two within the forloop.

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new thread for this, but the first number track (only 1 square) looks odd when it compiles. Why does this happen?

Comment: probably your lists, 1,2,3,...,2. Why don't you just draw them as fixed size nodes with their edges draw? Then no need to draw the boxes manually

Comment: @daleif I'm a bit of a programming newb. What did you mean by "fixed size nodes"? And what manual drawing is occurring? Doesn't the macro do it for me?

Comment: You are drawing the boxes, you don't need to, you can get the node to do it for you. Fixed size just means we specify in advance what size the node should have (since 1 and 20 does not have the same width)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\newcommand\numbertrack[2][1.15]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,
          mybox/.style={rectangle,draw,
                        minimum height=#1*10mm,
                        minimum width=#1*10mm}
    ]
    \foreach \num [count=\x] in {#2} {
      \node[mybox] at (\x,0){\num};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \numbertrack{1,2,3,...,16}

  \numbertrack{12,4,3,5,3,5,2,3,4}

  \numbertrack[0.5]{a,d,3,c,s,g,d,a}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The nodes are drawn with a rectangular boundary with the minimum width and height set according to the scale -- this is the only tricky part and is done by the `#1*10mm` in the style for `mybox`. For an explanation of the `minimum height` and `minimum width` settings see: [displaying-a-node-inside-a-foreach-loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337892/how-to-perform-addition-while-displaying-a-node-inside-a-foreach-loop/337894#337894). Except for the scaling, these two questions are very similar.

Notice that the `\numbertrack` macro takes an optional argument for the scale. So the last example, `\numbertrack[0.5]{a,d,3,c,s,g,d,a}`, sets the scale to `0.5`. By default, the scale is set to `1.15` as in the OP.

**EDIT**

If I have misunderstood and instead you just want the numbers from `1,2,...,x` then a slight variation on the code above works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\newcommand\numbertrack[2][1.15]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,
          mybox/.style={rectangle,draw,
                        minimum height=#1*10mm,
                        minimum width=#1*10mm}
    ]
    \foreach \num [count=\x] in {1,...,#2} {
      \node[mybox] at (\x,0){\num};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \numbertrack{16}

  \numbertrack{12}

  \numbertrack[0.5]{3}

  \numbertrack[2]{1}

  \numbertrack[2]{0}

  \numbertrack[2]{-5}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

In particular, `1` is not a special case. Negative numbers work too, but probably not as you'd want:(

Comment: `\foreach \num [count=\x] in {#2}` is just clever!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using just nodes. Because of the `\foreach`, 1 is a special case

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\def\myscale{1.15}

\newcommand\drawnumber[1]{
  \node[draw,anchor=west,
        minimum width=5mm,
        minimum height=5mm] (B) at (A) {#1};
  \coordinate (A) at ($(B.east)+(-\pgflinewidth,0)$);
}

\newcommand{\numbertrack}[1]
{
  \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0); % initialize
  \ifnum#1=1\drawnumber{1}\fi
  \ifnum#1>1\relax
  \foreach\x in {1,2,...,#1}{
    \drawnumber{\x}
  }
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\par
\bigskip
}

\newcommand{\mytracks}
{
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3,...,20} {
      \numbertrack{\y}
    }
 }

\begin{document}

\mytracks

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `\ifnum#1=2` condition is unnecessary since `\numbertrack{2}` would work (`\foreach \x in {1,2,...,2}{\x }` prints `1 2 `).

Comment: @ebo you're right, I've updated the example