# How to perform arithmetic operations

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to draw polygons and label nodes at their corners in clockwise order.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, thick, main node/.style={circle, draw, font = 
\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\foreach \a in {2,...,4}{
    % make polygon
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\a, minimum size=3cm] at (\a*4,0) (A) {};
    % draw nodes
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\a}{
        \node[circle, draw] (\a\i) at (A.corner \i) {\i};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result looks like the following:

[image: ![result]

In order to make the labels follow the clockwise order, I tried to perform arithmetic operations on `\i` and `\a` directly:

```
\node[circle, draw] (\a\i) at (A.corner \i) {\a - \i + 1};
```

which failed to reach my goal:

[image: ![WrongResult]

How should arithmetic operations be properly performed in this context?

Comment: Try `\node[circle, draw] (\a\i) at (A.corner \i) {\the\numexpr\a-\i+1};`.

Comment: Node text doesn't get evaluated, just like everything in TeX. For integer operations you can use `\numexpr` as  per the other comment or with an uptodate distribution the included top-level `\inteval{\a-\i+1}`. If you want to use PGFMath you can use `\pgfmathprint(\a-\i+1)` but for simple integer arithmetics `\inteval` should be preferred. With `\foreach` you can also use the [`evaluate` key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457022). [Another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337892).

Comment: You could add `xscale=-1` to the `\node` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with every text in TeX, node text doesn't get evaluated.

That's just PGF/TikZ that throws almost everything in PGFMath and evaluates it but it doesn't touch literal text.

For simple integer arithmetics you can use LaTeX3/l3int's `\inteval` (which is just a top-level shortcut for the plain `\the\numexpr`):

```
\node[circle, draw] (\a\i) at (A.corner \i) {\inteval{\a - \i + 1}};
```

If you want to keep using PGFMath, you can do `\pgfmathprint{int(\a-\i+1)}`.

The `regular polygon sides = 2` results in an error which is why I leave it out in the code below.

---

But instead of math you can also invert the shape and rotate it in such a way that the first corner is where you want it, then you only have to label them as they are.

Since you don't do anything with the `regular polygon` shape but use its corners you can just place the circular nodes directly at the coordinates.

To make that easier, I'll provide one solution via the `chains` library (and an alternative that uses basically the same approach but manually instead of a neat chain placement rule).

The `graphs` libraries make it even easier via the circular placement rule `clockwise`.

All you need to specify there are the number of nodes (`n = …`) and where the first one starts (`phase = …`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard, chains, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikz[% A: regular polygon shape
  n/.style={
    shape=regular polygon, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon sides={#1},
    outer sep=+0pt, xscale=-1, rotate={180-isodd(#1)*180/(#1)}},
  c/.style={circle, draw},
] \foreach \i in {3, ..., 5}
    \node[n=\i] at (right:4*\i) (A) {}
      node foreach \j in {1, ..., \i}
        [c] at (A.corner \j) {\j};

\tikz[% B1: nodes placed in a circle (chains)
  nodes={shape=circle, draw, on chain},
  poly/.style={at=({270+180/(#1)-(\tikzchaincount-1)*360/(#1)}:1.5cm)},
] \foreach \i in {2, ..., 5}
    \path[shift=(right:4*\i), start chain=placed {poly=\i}]
      node foreach \j in {1, ..., \i} {\j};

\tikz[% B2: nodes placed in a circle (w/o chains)
  nodes={shape=circle, draw},
] \foreach[count=\r] \i in {2, ..., 5}
    \node foreach \j in {1, ..., \i}
      [shift=(right:4*\r)] at ({270+180/\i-(\j-1)*360/\i}:1.5cm) {\j};

\tikz[% C: nodes placed in a circle (graphs)
 nodes={shape=circle, draw},
 graphs/every graph/.append style={clockwise, radius=1.5cm},
 graphs/poly/.style={n={#1}, phase=270+180/(#1)},
] \foreach \i in {2, ..., 5}
    \path[shift=(right:4*\i)] graph {subgraph I_n[poly=\i]};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]